# Kafka Streams KTable-KTable outerJoin emits oldValue instead of newValue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Currently, I have an implementation where I have with three KTables and two outerJoins. Conceptually ( I can't post the actual code, as it is not open source):

KTableOne, KTableTwo, KTableThree, IntermediateKTable. The configuration for the KTables are all the same and are essentially

```
...Materialize.as<~>("storeNameX".withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
.withValueSerde(xSerde).withCachingDisabled()
```

The flow is:

Step (1):
`IntermediateKTable = Ktable1.outerJoin(KTable2)`

Step (2): `intermediateKTable.outerJoin(KTable3)` and I emit this to a Topic.

In code it loosely looks like this:

```
KTable<String, A> IntermediateKTable = kTableOne.outerJoin(kTableTwo);

KTableThree.outerJoin(intermediateKTable).toStream().to("topicName", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), outputSerde);
```

**And here comes the question**

When an update is being edited from Step (1), the older record is what gets propagated to the second outer join and I can see that the correct and updated value has in fact been persisted in the KTable after the new event has propagated through.

I have stepped through the debugger and found the culprit to be in the `KTableKTableOuterJoin.class`:

within the `process` method.

I have `this.context().forward(key, new Change(newValue, oldValue), To.all().withTimestamp(resultTimestamp)`. In this case `oldValue` is what gets propagated to the processing node that is upcoming and not `newValue`. I would like to have `newValue` to be propagated to the second join. (https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/KTableKTableOuterJoin.java#L118)

I have been reading the join semantics here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Join+Semantics#KafkaStreamsJoinSemantics-KTable-KTableJoin.1

and have set cache.max.buffering.size=0.

The output semantic of the outerJoin is actually exactly the behaviour that I am hoping for this topology but not seeing in the implementation.

I appreciate all your help in advance.

**Update**

So after I added a
`.toStream().groupByKey().reduce((oldValue, newValue) -> newValue, Materialized.as(...))` and then did the chaining.

The output of the last join emits both the `oldValue` and the `newValue`. In that order. This is now correct but does not seem like an ideal solution.

Comment: I had the similar problem, a chain of `.toStream().toTable()` helped me, but it is a workaround, not a solution. Have you found the reason?